# ¿Como puedo obtener los datos de una lista que llegan por un procedimiento almacenado de una forma más dinámica?

Tags: c#

Estoy usando un procedimiento almacenado que obtengo de SQL Server para obtener una lista de datos de un empleado para mostrarla en su liquidación de sueldo, este procedimiento lo meto en una variable para poder ir recorriendo los datos y asignar los montos en unas variables para poder ir mostrando cada dato en el documento, la cosa que me gustaría hacerlo algo más dinámico para no ocupar tanto código, pero no se me ocurre como poder hacerlo.

Lo hice así y también podría hacerlo con switch, pero no sé si se podrá hacerlo con menos código

Esta es la variable donde uso los datos del procedimiento

```
var idContrato = 1;
var periodo = 2022;



 var pa = db.pa_listadatosliquidacion(idContrato, periodo).ToList();
```

Las variables del documento

```
        var bonoMeta = 0;
        var anticipo = 0;
        var montoSueldo = 0;
        var colacion = 0;
        var movilizacion = 0;
        var gratificacionP = 0;
        var asignacion = 0;
        var salud = 0;
        var afp = 0;
        var impuesto = 0;
        var seguro = 0;
        var horas = 0;
        var aquinaldo = 0;
        var bonoEspecial = 0;
        var bonoMontaje = 0;
        var comisiones = 0;
        var fiestasPatrias = 0;
        var navidad = 0;
```

Metodo para obtener los datos y asignar las variables

```
        foreach (var p in pa)

        {
            if (p.descripcion == "Aguinaldo Navidad")
            {
                navidad = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);

            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Aguinaldo Fiestas Patrias")
            {
                fiestasPatrias = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);

            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Comisiones")
            {
                comisiones = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);

            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Aquinaldo")
            {
                aquinaldo = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);

            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Bono Especial")
            {
                bonoEspecial = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);

            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Bono Montaje")
            {
                bonoMontaje = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);

            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Horas extras")
            {
                horas = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Bono Meta")
            {
                bonoMeta = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Asignacion familiar")
            {
                asignacion = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            };
            if (p.descripcion == "Gratificación")
            {
                gratificacionP = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Sueldo Base")
            {
                montoSueldo = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Anticipo Sueldo")
            {
                anticipo = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }

            if (p.descripcion == "Colación")
            {
                colacion = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }

            if (p.descripcion == "Movilización")
            {
                movilizacion = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Isapre")
            {
                salud = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
            if (p.descripcion == "AFP")
            {
                afp = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Impuesto único")
            {
                impuesto = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
            if (p.descripcion == "Seguro de cesantía")
            {
                seguro = Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dos cosas: 0: creo que un `switch` podría ayudar con la legibilidad; igual se traducirá a los `if`'s que tienes ahí, sin embargo, se leerá mejor. 1: en lugar de tener las descripciones *hardcoded*, pues hacer una clase estática con strings estáticos. 2: Las cadenas de caracteres es preferible compararlas utilizando `.Equals()`

Comment: Hay alguna razón por la que el procedimiento devuelve la información en ese formato? Puedes cambiar ese procedimiento o esta fuera de tu control?  Un `switch` reduciría bastante el código pero no se estaría resolviendo el verdadero problema.

Comment: Esta fuera de mi control ese procedimiento, solo puedo obtener los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías ocupar atributos

Digamos que tienes la clase Sueldo

```
public class Sueldo
{

    public int bonoMeta {get; set;}
    public int anticipo {get; set;}
    public int montoSueldo {get; set;}
    public int colacion {get; set;}
    public int movilizacion {get; set;}
    public int gratificacionP {get; set;}
    public int asignacion {get; set;}
    public int salud {get; set;}
    public int afp {get; set;}
    public int impuesto {get; set;}
    public int seguro {get; set;}
    public int horas {get; set;}
    public int aquinaldo {get; set;}
    public int bonoEspecial {get; set;}
    public int bonoMontaje {get; set;}
    public int comisiones {get; set;}
    public int fiestasPatrias {get; set;}
    public int navidad {get; set;}
}
```

Deberás crear una Clase atributo de esta forma

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class NombreAtribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string Nombre { get; set;}
    public NombreAtribute(string Nombre) => this.Nombre = Nombre;
}
```

Luego colocar los atributos en la clase Sueldo y crear una función para setear los valores

```
public class Sueldo
{
    [NombreAtribute("Bono Meta")]
    public int bonoMeta {get; set;}

    [NombreAtribute("Anticipo Sueldo")]
    public int anticipo {get; set;}

    [NombreAtribute("Sueldo Base")]
    public int montoSueldo {get; set;}
   
    //Etc...(El resto de la propiedades)

    public void Set(string nombre, int valor)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Sueldo).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            NombreAtribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(NombreAtribute)) as NombreAtribute;
            if (attribute != null && attribute.Nombre == nombre)
            {
                property.SetValue(this, valor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y luego en el foreach de tu código quedaría asi:

```
var sueldo =  new Suedo();
foreach (var p in pa){
 sueldo.set(p.descripcion , Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto));
}
```

---

Otra opción es que simplemente ocuparas un diccionario

```
Dictionary<string,int> sueldoValores = new Dictionary<string,int>();
foreach (var p in pa){
 sueldoValores.Add(p.descripcion , Convert.ToInt32(p.Monto));
}
```

Claro que para después llamar un valor debes recordad el texto

```
Textbox1.text = sueldoValores["Anticipo Sueldo"];
```